# Не отображается рамка в браузерах

Tags: css

вот скрипт обясните в чем ошибка

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    background:#ffffff;
    width:975px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:16px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    top:-21px;
    border: 13px;
    -moz-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13  stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13 stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13 stretch;
    border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13  round stretch;
}
```

заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1):

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    background:#ffffff;
    width:975px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:16px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    top:-21px;
    border: 13px solid #FFF;
    -moz-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13  stretch;
    -webkit-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13 stretch; 
    -o-border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13 stretch;
    border-image: url(img/border.jpg) 13  round stretch;
}
```